# You receive a mysterious tape

Tags: cipher

You receive a mysterious package from someone with a tape inside it. You run the tape into your computer, but it says it's corrupted. You then take the raw bits, and they come out like this:

```
0011010100110110001101010011011100110100010000010011011100110001001101000011100100110100001110000011010000110110001100110011001000110110001100110011010100110011001101000011001000110111001100110011010100111001001101100100010000110110001101110011011000110111001101100011001100110011001100110011010101000001001100110011000000110110001100010011010000110111001101010011011000110111001110010011010000111001001101000011011100110100010000010011011001000110001101010100000100110111001110010011010000110010001101100100010100110110001101000011010100111000001101000011100100110110001101110011010100111001001100110011001000110110001110000011011100110100001101100011001000110101001110000011011001000011001101110011100100110101001100000011011100110111001101100100011000110110001101110011010000111001001101000011001100110100001100010011011000110111001101000100001100110101001100110011010000110010001101000011001000110110001100100011011001000100001101100011010000110011001100010011011000110010001101100100010000110100001101010011001101000100
```

Hint:

> Someone, possibly the same person, sends you an email that looks like this:
> `WW91IGtub3cgaGUgbGlrZXMgcGlja2xlcywgYW5kIGhlIGxpa2VzIGNhc3Rpbmcgc3BlbGxzLiBIb3cgaXMgdGhpcyBlbmNvZGVkIGFnYWluPyBJdCBzZWVtcyBsaWtlIHRoZSBsZXR0ZXJzIGFyZSBkb2luZyBoYWxmIHR1cm5zLCBzbyBjYW4geW91IHBsZWFzZSBsZXQgZ28gb2YgdGhlIHVzdWFsIGJhc2UncyBzaGlmdCBrZXk/IFlvdSBmb3VuZCBzb21lIG9mIGhpcyBzdHVmZiBpbiBiaW5zLg==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The message, when ASCII decoded, says **56574A714948463263534273596D676763335A306147567949474A6F5A79426E645849675932687462586C7950776F67494341674C534242626D6431626D453D**, which is **VWJqIHF2cSBsYmggc3Z0aGVyIGJoZyBndXIgY2htbXlyPwogICAgLSBBbmd1bmE=** when interpreting as a hex-string.
>  Decoding this with a Base64, we get:
>
> ```
> Ubj qvq lbh svther bhg gur chmmyr?
> - Anguna
> ```
>
> Applying ROT13, we get
>
> ```
> How did you figure out the puzzle?
>     - Nathan
> ```

So

> this seems to be a final answer, since Nathan is the name of the puzzle creator.

Hint

> The email is a Base64 encoded message which says: *You know he likes pickles, and he likes casting spells. How is this encoded again? It seems like the letters are doing half turns, so can you please let go of the usual base's shift key? You found some of his stuff in bins.*
>  Some thoughts about the email: encoded again = multiple ASCII and Base 64 encodings, half turns = ROT13 (13 is a half of the 26-letter alphabet), shift key = ROT13 again, bins = binary (Base-2) system of the original message.

Comment: In case you wondered, the pickle reference was because I was originally planning to make a Python pickle.

Comment: 'He likes casting spells' was a clue about hex.

Comment: I've thought about `pickle` module, and for casting spells my thought was about the type casting on programming.